# Regular Expression to match [php]code[/php]

Tags: php, regex

As part of a project, I need to analyse string which may contain a reference to PHP in the following manner:

`[php]functionName(args1, args2)[/php]`

The function name is not always the same, and I would like to replace everything in the above example (including the pseudo-tags) with another value.

Can anyone suggest a Regular Expression to effectively match the pattern `[php]anything[/php]`.

Sorry if this is a basic question, but I suck at Regular Expressions!

Comment: See also: [open source regex tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world) which could help with creating the according match pattern.

Comment: is it your intent to match anything between your start and end pseudo tags or only PHP function calls?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think `"\[php\](.*?)\[\/php\]"` would do the trick.

Edit: you may or may not need the double quotes-- not sure how you're ultimately using the regex string.

Answer (score 3):

**If** constructs like `[ php ]`, `[/*comment/*php]` (or other crazy stuff) are not allowed, you can use this:

```
/\[php\](.*?)\[\/php\]/
```

The first matched group will be the text inside the tags. I think the regex is quite intuitive, except for the `?`: it will be lazy and match text only until the first closing tag, so that if you have `[php]...[/php]   [php]...[/php]` the regex will not match `...[/php]   [php]...` (that is, between the first `[php]` and the second `[/php]`)

Comment: no sweat.  definitely +1 on your answer for the additional explanation / info.

Comment: Capture is not needed since OP wants to replace the entire pattern.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

$s = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, [php]functionName(args1, args2)[/php] ok.";

echo preg_replace("/\[php\][^\[]+\[\/php\]/", "seems to work", $s) . "\n";

// prints => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, seems to work ok.

?>
```

Comment: what about `[php]func($somearray[0])[/php]` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using WordPress, but sure to look into the shortcode API.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

And if not consider grabbing its code. It was written so it could be used in any app.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$start_tag ='\\\\[php\\\\]\\\\s*';
$function  ='((\\\\w+)\\\\s*\\\\(([^)]*)\\\\)';
$end_tag   ='\\\\s*\\\\[\\\\/php\\\\]';

$re='/(' . $start_tag . $function . $end_tag . ')/';
```

which is:

```
(                 # start capture group #1 - full match
\[                # literal '['
php               # literal 'php'
\]                # literal ']'
\s*               # optional whitespace
(                 # start capture group #2 - full function
  (               # start capture group #3 - function name
    \w+           # one or more word chars [A-Za-z0-9_]
  )               # end capture group #3
  \(              # literal '('
    (             # start capture group #4 - function arguments
      [^)]*       # zero or more non-')' chars
    )             # end capture group #4
  \)              # literal ')'
)                 # end capture group #2
\s*               # optional whitespace
\[                # literal '['
php               # literal 'php'
\]                # literal ']'
)                 # end capture group #1
```

Comment: Note that neither '\w+' nor '[^)]*' need to be non-greedy ('lazy') because they are both bounded by succeeding chars.

Comment: Since PHP prohibits identifiers from beginning with a digit, change '\w+' to '[A-Za-z_]\w*' to only match legal function names.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
\[php\](.*)\[\/php\]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search for string between these tags eg

```
\[PHP\](.+[^\b\[])\[/PHP\]
```

Comment: Shouldn't 'PHP' be 'php' to match the OP's criteria?

Comment: -1 since your solution would fail to match '[php]f(a, b)[/php]' since both ',' and space are word boundaries.